# Button on top of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a canvas and I want to place an html Element over that canvas using css. I want the button to stay in place in the canvas when you resize the whole entire page and currently I have this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/z4fhrhLc/

```
#button {position:absolute; top:40%; left:30%;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relatively position an element without it taking up space in document flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040005/relatively-position-an-element-without-it-taking-up-space-in-document-flow)

Comment: Referencing the duplicate mentioned, place your button and canvas in a container then used the approaches mentioned to relatively position it on-top of the canvas without it taking up space in the Document (*you may want to define `z-index` for each one to ensure the button is on top*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an additional container for both `canvas` and `button`. Here is how it would work

```css
.canvas-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:lightgrey
}
#button {
  position:absolute;
  left:30%;
  top:40%
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
 <canvas id='canvas' width='500px' height='500px'></canvas>
<button id='button'>Whats up</button> 
</div>
```

You have to set `canvas-container`'s `width` and `height` to same as canvas `height` and `width` otherwise button position will change.

Comment: You just taught me something new and you fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: Great, glad that you learned something new. Make sure to select as correct answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

try changing the  `#canvas` to `position: relative;`

Comment: If you also set z-index: -1 it will be a valid answer!