# Generate tooltip on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we have a function `generateTooltip()` that generates and returns the html of a tooltip for DOM element `el`. How can I get this tooltip to be generated and shown ***on demand*** (hover)?

## Background

I suppose one could generate the tooltip beforehand and assign the pre-generated html as a tooltip to `el`, but I want the generation to be ***lazy*** as my `generateTooltip(i,j)` defines many rich tooltips for the cells of a large table.

(Currently I'm only using jQuery but would add a library if necessary.)

## Edit

***Emphasis*** added to prevent further misunderstanding. The tooltip shouldn't be pre-generated on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for...

```
$("table td.hoverTarget").hover(function(){
    var hovered = $(this);
    var cellIndex = hovered.eq();
    var rowIndex =  hovered.parent().eq();
    if(hovered.children(".tooltipClass").length) {
         hovered.children(".tooltipClass").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        activeTooltip = generateTooltip(rowIndex,cellIndex);
        hovered.append(activeTooltip);
    }
}, function(){
     var hovered = $(this);
     hovered.children(".tooltipClass").fadeOut();
});
```

Here's a fiddle ==> [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/72rtksc6/)

Comment: Why don't you use Bootstrap's tooltips then?

Comment: Because bootstrap library is too heavy for just this, and from what I can see, it doesn't support a callback to generate the tooltip dynamically. So it wouldn't help me.

Comment: Anyway I just want to let you know that you can customize the bootstrap.js build and get only what you need.
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#plugins

Answer (score 0):

This answer works on cells that are not yet generated when this code is run. (jQuery `.on()` does not support `hover` events.) It also places the tooltip outside (below) the relevant cell, in front of other cells/content.

```
$('table').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        var cell = $(this);
        if(cell.data('timeout') !== undefined){
            clearTimeout(cell.data('timeout'));
            cell.removeData('timeout');
            showTooltip(cell, false);
        }
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            showTooltip(cell, true);
        }, 300); // tooltip delay
        cell.data('timeout',timeout);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        var cell = $(this);
        if(cell.data('timeout') !== undefined){
            clearTimeout(cell.data('timeout'));
            cell.removeData('timeout');
        }
        showTooltip(cell, false);
    }
}, 'td.hoverTarget');

function showTooltip(cell, show){
    if(show){
        if(cell.children('.tooltipContainer').length == 0){
            var j = cell.parent().children('td').index(cell);
            var i = cell.parent().index();
            var tooltipContent = generateTooltip(i,j);
            if(tooltipContent){
                var tooltip = $('<div></div>').addClass('cellTooltip').append(tooltipContent);
                var ttc = $('<div></div>').addClass('tooltipContainer').append(tooltip);
                cell.append(ttc);
                tooltip.hide();
            }
        }
        cell.find('.cellTooltip').fadeIn();
    } else {
        cell.find('.cellTooltip').fadeOut();                    
    }
}

function generateTooltip(i, j){
    // ...
    return "HTML for large tooltip.";
}
```

CSS:

```
table td.hoverTarget>div.tooltipContainer {
    position: relative; /* see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040258/827280. */
}

table td.hoverTarget>div.tooltipContainer>.cellTooltip {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```